# Is it possible to drag markers that gets it coordinates from geojson file?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

It's difficult to put my question into words, but I'll try. I'm using leaflet. I have a layer that contains a lot of positions and info about streetlights, but some are bit out of position. So is it possible to drag markers that are positioned by geoJSON file info?

Bonus question (not so important at the moment): If dragging is possible, by any chance is there possibility to save those changes into geojson file also?

Code about that layer.

```
    tv = new L.geoJson(tv, {
     pointToLayer: function (feature, layer) {
            return L.marker(layer, {icon: asteriskorangeicon });
        },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature2,

    });
    function onEachFeature2(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
        layer.bindPopup("<br><b><big><u>ID: " + feature.properties.id + "</br></b></big></u><br> <b>01_NR: </b>" + feature.properties.nr01
        + "<br><b>Kilp:</b> " + feature.properties.kilp + "<br><b>Phase: </b>" + feature.properties.phase_03 + "<b><br>kand_t1_04: </b>" 
        + feature.properties.kand_t1_04 + "<b><br>kand_t2_05: </b>" + feature.properties.kand_t2_05 + "<br><b>kand_om_06: </b>" + feature.properties.kand_om_06 
        + "<br><b>kand_kp_07:</b> " + feature.properties.kand_kp_07 + " <br><br>"       
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Kristjan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make each of the markers created by L.geoJson draggable, all you need to do is add the following inside the onEachFeature function:

```
function onEachFeature2(feature, layer) {   
    layer.options.draggable = true;
    ...
```

Comment: Also should have mentioned that your 'tv' GeoJSON layer is kept in sync with any changes that you make through the map. You can drag markers round to your hearts content and then just call tv.toGeoJSON() method to get the updated GeoJSON from the layer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/) to edit your geoJSON. The UI allows you to drag your markers to the map and the geoJSON will then update to reflect these changes. See the gif below for more details on how to add and edit your geoJSON.

[image: geojson]

Answer (score 0):

Best to check out the [Leaflet API reference documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) - [the option is `dragging` on the markers object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-dragging).

```
return L.marker(layer, {icon: asteriskorangeicon, dragging: true });
```

Of course, this doesn't let you save the results to a layer. For that, use [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export features from the leaflet map, you could iterate over all layers and request the GeoJSON representation.

E.g.

```
map.eachLayer(function(layer){
  if(layer.toGeoJSON){
    console.log(layer.toGeoJSON())
  }
});
```